# Loudness in espeak

Tags: volume, espeak

How can we increase the loudness of the speech using espeak..?
I am using text to speech covertion using espeak and the os is raspbian os.
Please suggest me a syntax for increasing the volume in espeak.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is invoke the `-a` method like this:

```
espeak -a 30 "WHAT YOU WANT TO SAY"
```